# PHP - Get the current array with string

Tags: php

```
$form = array(
    array(
        'form' => 'Change Schedule',
        'data' => array(
                    array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-start',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-12',
                        'label'=>'Schedule'
                    )
            ),
    ),
    array(
        'form' => 'Maintenance',
        'data' => array(
                    array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-room-place',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-12',
                        'label'=>'Room # / Place'
                    )
            ),
    ),
);
```

This is the `array` I made, I wanted to get the array with `form` = `Maintenance` only. Is this possible with `php` to get the array via `string arrays` I want to pass?

My attempt:
`$form(('form'=>'Change Dormitory'));`

Comment: you usually access arrays via pointing to the appropriate index `echo $form[1]['form']`, like so, it seems you're having trouble with the basics, maybe you ought to try reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 arrays inside the first array, so the internal arrays are $form[0] or $form[1].

You could then do $form[1]["form"] to get "Maintenance"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the array data inside `form = "Maintenance"`,

you can filter by `form` value like this:

```
$newForm = array();
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['form'] == 'Maintenance') {
        $arr[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($newForm);
```